# Plotting different lines on a single plot

Tags: plot

I kindly need help with plotting different lines on a single plot

For instance, I have

a = 1;

theta = [0 30 60 90];

d1 = a.*sind(theta);

d2 = a.*cosd(theta);

plot (d1,d2)

However, I also want to plot a seperate lines for a=2,3,4 on the same plot.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is this Matlab/Octave? If so, it is completely off-topic here I'm afraid, [so] would be better. (You can do `plot(x1,y1,x2,y2,...)` or `plot(x,y);hold on;plot(x2,y2);`)

Answer (score 1):

Is it something like this you're looking for?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[domain=0:90,no markers]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,3,4}{
      \addplot ({#1*sin(x)},{#1*cos(x)});
      \addlegendentry{$a = #1$};
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]